# C++ Sorting the "percentage" of two paired integer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, casting

I have a program with 2 "paired" integer arrays newNumerator[ ], and newDenominator[ ] which both have 9 integers in them.  I wrote a function that sorts them in ascending order, however I'm not sure it works as I have not gotten it to successfully compile yet.  I am having some issues with typecasting too. Here is the function definition-

```
void sortData(int *newNumerator[], int *newDenominator[], int newSize)
{
    int temp1;
    int temp2;
    bool swap;
    int count = 0;
    double percentageLeft = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(newNumerator[count]) / newDenominator[count];
    double percentageRight = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(newNumerator[count + 1]) / newDenominator[count + 1];

    do
    {  swap = false;
        for(count = 0; count < (newSize - 1); count++)
        {
            if(percentageLeft > percentageRight)
            {
                temp1 = *newNumerator[count];
                *newNumerator[count] = *newNumerator[count + 1];
                *newNumerator[count + 1] = temp1;

                temp2 = *newDenominator[count];
                *newDenominator[count] = *newDenominator[count + 1];
                *newDenominator[count + 1] = temp2;

                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
```

The typecasting problem I am having is with percentageLeft and percentageRight because newNumerator[ ] and newDenominator[ ] are integer pointers, but to get the "percentage" of them i need it to be a double.  Not sure how to go about this.  Basically i just need to figure out how to solve this issue, and also know if my function even serves its purpose.  Any help is appreciated, and please let me know if there is anything I can further clarify

Comment: Please always include the error messages in the question also

Comment: right now the only one I'm getting is "161:38: Static_cast from 'int *' to 'double' is not allowed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error you have is that you are giving wrong values to `static_cast<>`. Later you use them correctly by dereferencing, but in the cast you are missing that.

What you need is:

```
double percentageLeft = 100.0 * static_cast<double>((*newNumerator)[count]) / *newDenominator[count];
double percentageRight = 100.0 * static_cast<double>((*newNumerator)[count + 1]) / *newDenominator[count + 1];
```

Added parentheses to make it explicitly clear what the dereferencing is.

Also if you are not changing the actual array pointers, but only the contents of the arrays, you can remove the dereferencing hassle altogether. If you define the function as

```
void sortData(int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int newSize)
```

you can just use the normal indexing without dereferencing every time you use it.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the typecast problem, however now when I call the function " sortData(newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize); " it says theres not matching for call to 'sortData', saying that "Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int **' for 1st argument"  How do I fix this?

Comment: @Sosa That means you are giving it an int, not a pointer to an int array, so you need to add information on how you are calling the function and with what argument types

Comment: Here is a pastebin for all the code in its entirety.  The error is coming from line 45- http://pastebin.com/R4LW5a51

Comment: @Sosa You are using `int[]` in other functions, but for this you chose `int*[]`. If you would change the code to use `int[]` in this one also, you would get rid of this error also since you are giving it `int[]` and it expects `int*[]`

Comment: I did try it using 'int[ ]' but when I run the program, it doesnt "sort" the data.  It just outputs the data in the arrays in the same order, instead of the desired ascending.  Any idea why its doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I propose using the STL for sorting. Makes things simpler and more understandable.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Ratio
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    double toDouble() const
    {
        return static_cast<double>(numerator)
             / static_cast<double>(denominator);
    }

    bool operator < (Ratio const& other) const
    {
        return toDouble() < other.toDouble();
    }
};

void main()
{
    std::vector<Ratio> ratios = { {1, 2}, {5, 7}, {2, 11} };
    std::sort(ratios.begin(), ratios.end());
}
```

Dealing with raw arrays and sorting manually is almost always the more tedious and error prone approach.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for reference

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I have a program with 2 "paired" integer arrays newNumerator[ ], and newDenominator[ ]

Yet your function defined as:

```
void sortData(int *newNumerator[], int *newDenominator[], int newSize)
```

I think that should be:

```
void sortData(int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int newSize)
```

If that is indeed the case, then the lines:

```
temp1 = *newNumerator[count];
*newNumerator[count] = *newNumerator[count + 1];
*newNumerator[count + 1] = temp1;

temp2 = *newDenominator[count];
*newDenominator[count] = *newDenominator[count + 1];
*newDenominator[count + 1] = temp2;
```

need to be:

```
temp1 = newNumerator[count]; // Remove the *
newNumerator[count] = newNumerator[count + 1];
newNumerator[count + 1] = temp1;

temp2 = newDenominator[count];
newDenominator[count] = newDenominator[count + 1];
newDenominator[count + 1] = temp2;
```